# Hyphen and en dash usage in adjectives such as "human–animal"

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, dashes

I noticed a possible editorial error in Nature magazine concerning this. These two headlines **[here](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01001-2)** and **[here](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-02275-3)** use en dashes and hyphens for the adjectives "human–animal" and "human-animal" respectably.

In both articles, the en dash version is used but in the headlines, there is a difference. Is this some kind of error? I'm guessing the en dash version is the correct one but could someone explain to me why that is?

Comment: This is a novel compound premodifier and takes the usual hyphen. In some 'triple-barrelled' premodifiers, some style guides recommend hyphen and dash be used in tandem, but that is not the case here.

Comment: It seems to me that the usage of the hyphenated version is more common. Check **[this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=human-animal%2Chuman--animal&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3)** out. But it seems like both are used in tandem.

Comment: Since hyphenated words use hyphens, the shortest dash, could the headlines have their own font quirk?

Comment: @YosefBaskin In the articles, the en dash is used throughout. Only in that one headline is the hyphen used. That's why I thought it an error, although Ngram results show that the hyphen version is much more common.