# Can there be two different hyphens in multi-word compounds in English?

Tags: hyphenation

In Wiley's redaction, they edited our hyphens in our article title, so we have now two different hyphens there:

> Extension of Pradel capture–recapture survival‐recruitment model
> accounting for transients

The first hyphen is probably n-dash, the second one is hyphen. The term "capture–recapture" is an established one, that has been used a lot in literature. Whereas the term  "survival‐recruitment" was created by us to signify that the model is for calculating both survival and recruitment.

So, is there a valid reason for two different hyphens in these multi-word compounds? Are there some guidelines or habits in English that could lead to these two different hyphens?

PS: Wiley can make mistakes; they made a lot of corrections which were not grammatically ok..

EDIT: I got an interesting answer from ChatGPT 4.0, posted it as an answer.

PS2: got an [interesting answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/615672/13045):

> **south-west–north-east**: Hyphens are used within each direction, and en-dashes are used between directions.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574791/hyphen-and-en-dash-usage-in-adjectives-such-as-human-animal) is about a similar issue, but doesn't have any answers. Most likely it's incorrect application of style rules.

Comment: You are misusing the word redaction.

Comment: Why don't you ask the copyeditor directly for his/her reasons? That would seem to be more useful for your purposes rather than asking the people on this site to guess what the copyeditor's reasons may have been.

Comment: Didn't know terms could hold internal n-dashes instead of hyphens. I demand a retraction.

Comment: I am voting to reopen, as the duplicates do not address why *capture–recapture* would be styled with an en dash. It’s not because it sits in front of another hyphenated term. I can answer why it is styled that way (and whether or not it should be) if the question is reopened.

Comment: The punctuation 'rules' hereabouts are hardly standardised, and any attempt to further complicate the << 'use of hyphen + en-dash' advice (see [Tin Hat's CMOS quote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/612134/should-i-hyphenate-haunted-mansion-themed-outfit/612141#612141)) for compound adjectives when one of their elements itself consists of an open compound >> should in my opinion be hastily abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

If "*the model is for calculating both survival and recruitment*", 'survival-recruitment' is not a compound.
You could write it as "**survival/recruitment**", with the slash as a substitute for the conjunction 'or' (both inclusive and exclusive).